# Why do I face errors only during main thread but it doesn't happen during pool1-thread

Tags: spring, multithreading, maven, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am getting one "not-fatal" error twice and one "No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] is defined" imediatly after I ran java -jar myApp.jar. After the main thread fineshed and the thread from spool started, there is no more error and my apllication run as expected (i.e. the application triggers the job as scheduled and ran accordingly). I noted that the first two not-fatal errors happen after certain property is searched but it never happens during pool1-thread.
I am completely stuck and I must deploy it to server for first tests and I don't have any idea why is the root cause neither I guess a possibility to investigate.
I noted something strange (at least strange for someone with my knowledge): why all properties are searched in three places: SystemProperty, SystemEnvironment and my config.properties? I clearly specified only config.properties! Maybe it is not related to my issue since there are few others properties settup the same way in same config.property file and used in same class with no errors but, by the way, I noted that the not-fatal errors happen always after the "stat" property is searched.

The spring batch configuration

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource("config.properties")
public class BatchConfiguration {
... just a simple spring batch with a very simple job containing a very simple read, process and writer methods
```

The most relevant class, I mean the scheduler

```
@Component
public class QueueScheduler {
    private Job job;
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    public QueueScheduler(JobLauncher jobLauncher, @Qualifier("job") Job job){
        this.job = job;
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
   }

   @Scheduled(fixedRate=60000)
   public void runJob(){
          try{
       jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
          }catch(Exception ex){
                 log.info(ex.getMessage());
          }
   }
}
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>com.example</groupId>
       <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <packaging>jar</packaging>
       <name>demo</name>
       <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
       <parent>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
              <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
              <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
       </parent>
       <properties>
              <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
              <java.version>1.8</java.version>
              <spring.batch.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
       </properties>
       <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                     <scope>test</scope>
              </dependency>
       </dependencies>
       <build>
              <plugins>
                     <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                     </plugin>
                     <plugin>
                           <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                           <configuration>
                                  <archive>
                                         <manifest>
                                                <mainClass>com.example.DemoAppNoBoot</mainClass>
                                         </manifest>
                                  </archive>
                                  <descriptorRefs>
                                         <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                                  </descriptorRefs>
                           </configuration>
                           <executions>
                                  <execution>
                                         <phase>install</phase>
                                         <goals>
                                                <goal>single</goal>
                                         </goals>
                                  </execution>
                           </executions>
                     </plugin>
                     <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                           <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>2.5.1</version>
                           <configuration>
                                  <goals>install</goals>
                                  <preparationGoals>install</preparationGoals>
                           </configuration>
                     </plugin>
                     <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                           <configuration>
                                  <archive>
                                         <manifest>
                                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                                <mainClass>com.example.DemoAppNoBoot</mainClass>
                                         </manifest>
                                  </archive>
                           </configuration>
                     </plugin>
              </plugins>
       </build>
</project>
```

The only place the stat variable is used

```
@Component
public class Queue {
       @Autowired
       private Environment env;
...
env.getProperty("stat")
```

The three errors message immediatly after I ran java -jar myApp.jar. Note the first two are "a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable".

```
13:24:57.528 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'hours-add-servertime' in [systemProperties]
13:24:57.528 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'hours-add-servertime' in [systemEnvironment]
13:24:57.529 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'hours-add-servertime' in [class path resource [config.properties]]
13:24:57.529 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'h
ours-add-servertime' in [class path resource [config.properties]] with type [Str
ing] and value '-7'
13:24:57.531 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'stat' in [systemProperties]
13:24:57.531 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'stat' in [systemEnvironment]
13:24:57.532 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'stat' in [class path resource [config.properties]]
13:24:57.533 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 's
tat' in [class path resource [config.properties]] with type [String] and value '
C:/MYAPP/Configurations/stat.xml'
13:24:57.884 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.t.c.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor - Failed
to class-load type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error,
but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.web.config.EnableSpri
ngDataWebSupport
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0
_65]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(La
unchedURLClassLoader.java:178) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(Laun
chedURLClassLoader.java:142) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttribu
tesVisitor.visitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:47) ~[spring-core-
4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.
java:1802) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:642) [spr
ing-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:508) [spr
ing-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init
>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:64) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactor
y.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELE
ASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFacto
ry.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102) [spring-core-4.2.4.R
ELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactor
y.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELE
ASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoCo
nfigurationClasses.<init>(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:112) [spring-boot-autocon
figure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.getInP
riorityOrder(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:56) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.R
ELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportS
elector.sort(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:173) [spring-boot-autoco
nfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportS
elector.selectImports(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:82) [spring-boo
t-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.proce
ssDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:453) [spring-context-4.2
.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse
(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RE
LEASE]
.... (I took out the lines to make more easy to read)...
text.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84) [spring-context-4.2.4.RE
LEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at com.example.DemoAppNoBoot.main(DemoAppNoBoot.java:12) [demo-0.0.1-SNA
PSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.
0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner
.java:53) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
13:24:58.830 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'spring.messages.basename' in [systemProperties]
13:24:58.835 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'spring.messages.basename' in [systemEnvironment]
13:24:58.836 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'spring.messages.basename' in [class path resource [config.properties]]
13:24:58.837 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not fi
nd key 'spring.messages.basename' in any property source. Returning [null]





…
13:25:01.353 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'hours-add-servertime' in [systemProperties]
13:25:01.354 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'hours-add-servertime' in [systemEnvironment]
13:25:01.354 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'hours-add-servertime' in [class path resource [config.properties]]
13:25:01.355 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'h
ours-add-servertime' in [class path resource [config.properties]] with type [Str
ing] and value '-7'
13:25:01.356 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'stat' in [systemProperties]
13:25:01.357 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'stat' in [systemEnvironment]
13:25:01.358 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'stat' in [class path resource [config.properties]]
13:25:01.358 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 's
tat' in [class path resource [config.properties]] with type [String] and value '
C:/MYAPP/Configurations/stat.xml'
13:25:01.473 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.t.c.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor - Failed
to class-load type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error,
but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.web.config.EnableSpri
ngDataWebSupport
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0
_65]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
       at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(La
unchedURLClassLoader.java:178) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(Laun
chedURLClassLoader.java:142) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttribu
tesVisitor.visitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:47) ~[spring-core-
4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.
java:1802) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:642) [spr
ing-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
.... (I took out the lines to make more easy to read)...
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcesso
r.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) [s
pring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate
.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.ja
va:273) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate
.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) [spr
ing-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invoke
BeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) [spring-context-4
.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4
.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationCon
text.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84) [spring-context-4.2.4.RE
LEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at com.example.DemoAppNoBoot.main(DemoAppNoBoot.java:12) [demo-0.0.1-SNA
PSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.
0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner
.java:53) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
13:25:04.089 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cache
d instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
```

The third error is:

```
13:25:09.756 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Unable to
locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.sp
ringframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@6b1cff9f]
13:25:09.759 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cache
d instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
13:25:09.763 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cache
d instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalSch
eduledAnnotationProcessor'
13:25:09.764 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cache
d instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.Config
urationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor'
13:25:09.766 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.a.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Could n
ot find default TaskScheduler bean
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying b
ean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] is defined
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:
4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:
4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPost
Processor.finishRegistration(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:192) [spr
ing-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPost
Processor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:171) [spr
ing-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPost
Processor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:86) [spri
ng-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.i
nvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163) [spring-context-4.2.4.
RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.m
ulticastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136) [spring-context-4.2.4.
RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publis
hEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:
4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publis
hEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:
4.2.4.RELEASE]
... I took out several lines to make easy for reading ...
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner
.java:53) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
13:25:09.795 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
13:25:09.797 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
13:25:09.797 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching fo
r key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [class path resource [config.propert
ies]]
13:25:09.798 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not fi
nd key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [nul
l]
13:25:09.802 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cache
d instance of singleton bean 'jobLauncher'
```

No errors at all after the main thread fineshed and the thread from spool started

```
13:44:11.047 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'stat' in [systemProperties]
13:44:11.048 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'stat' in [systemEnvironment] 
13:44:11.048 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'stat' in [class path resource [config.properties]]
13:44:11.049 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'stat' in [class path resource [config.properties]] with type [String] and value 'C:/ICTT/Configurations/stat.xml'
```

Comment: None of the three errors is actually an error. They're all just debug log messages. Unless there's an underlying problem that you're trying to track down, you can just ignore them. Even better, turn off debug logging and you'll no longer see them.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comment. I am quite confused now probably in reason of certain wrong concept in my mind: how can "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" and "Could not find default TaskScheduler bean org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException" be ignored and even be considered not an error? I guess that is the reason someone gave -1 but honestly I have been researching for several days with this error messages and I didn't find an answer to apply in my case. Certainly I will turn off debugg in production but what could be possible causes for such exceptions?

Comment: Andy, other very useful comment very close to my question would be an explanation why it happens only during main thread and it doesn't appear during pool-1-thread-1. In fact, this is my core question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the three errors is actually an error. They're all just debug log messages about the inner-workings of Spring Boot and Spring Framework.

Spring Boot's auto-configuration contains configuration that switches on automatically when certain libraries are added to that classpath. As part of processing the configuration and deciding what should be switched on, an attempt to load a class that isn't on the classpath may occur. This is done in such a way that it doesn't prevent the application from starting. The first two debug messages that you have identified are a side-effect of this process. They are both occurring because `org.springframework.data.web.config.EnableSpringDataWebSupport` isn't on the classpath. This means that Spring Data's Web support will not be auto-configured.

The third message is an implementation detail of how Spring Framework determines which task scheduler to use. It's looking for a bean that implements `TaskScheduler`. The debug message is telling you that it hasn't found one. It then looks for a bean that implements `ScheduledExecutorService`. If it doesn't find one of those it falls back to using a default implementation.

You only see these debug messages on the main thread as they all occur while your application is starting up and all of the start up processing is performed on the main thread.